# Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'

Tags: android

I have already tried all dependencies of android support appcompatv7 from 19 through 24.
When I change appcompat to <21, it shows me error of Material Design and when I change it to 23, I am having following errors.

Any help would be appreciated.
Could not resolve the following and almost 32 other.

```
@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_holo_dark<br>
@drawable/abc_cab_background_top_holo_dark<br>
@drawable/abc_ic_cab_done_holo_dark<br>
```

**Error**

```
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
E:\Workspace\Intern\Quran\New\Pray Timmings\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewGoIcon'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewCloseIcon'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQuery'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchResultListItemHeight'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewAutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(198, 6) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewEditQueryBackground'.
Error:(241, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchDropdownBackground'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewSearchIcon'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextField'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewTextFieldRight'.
Error:(268, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'searchViewVoiceIcon'.
Error:(627, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'spinnerMode'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.prayer.times.almoazin"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.1.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    }
```